# How to use Curl to also output first 20 characters from the response?

Tags: bash, curl

I'm using curl to retrieve the http_code size_header redirect_url and Website Title with:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE="$1"
while read LINE; do
     curl -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -i -s -k -o >(perl -l -0777 -ne 'print $1 if /<title.*?>\s*(.*?)\s*<\/title/si') --silent --max-time 2 --write-out '%{http_code} %{size_header} %{redirect_url} ' "$LINE"
       echo " $LINE"
   done < ${FILE}
```

but I like to also retrieve the first 20 characters from the response to have more information.

The idea is to get this output

```
%{http_code} %{size_header} %{redirect_url} $website_title $website_first_20_bytes
```

I only need to add the $website_first_20_bytes to the output. How can I achieve this?

PS: No the first 20 characters from header response. Only the source.

Comment: It is not clear what is that you need. You want only first 20 characters from `$LINE`?

Comment: Yes. Only that. 

In order to get that output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you probably mean something like this then (I added a bunch of newlines etc. to the output which you can trim as you please):

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE="$1"
while read -r LINE; do
     # read the response to a variable
     response=$(curl -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -s -k --max-time 2 --write-out '%{http_code} %{size_header} %{redirect_url} ' "$LINE")
     # get the title
     title=$(sed -n 's/.*<title>\(.*\)<\/title>.*/\1/ip;T;q'<<<"$response")
     # read the write-out from the last line
     read -r http_code size_header redirect_url < <(tail -n 1 <<<"$response")
     printf "Status: %s\n" "$http_code"
     printf "Size: %s\n" "$size_header"
     printf "Redirect-url: %s\n" "$redirect_url"
     printf "Url: %s\n" "$LINE"
     printf "Title: %s" "$title"
     # -c 20 only shows the 20 first chars from response
     printf "Body: %s" "$(head -c 20 <<<"$response")" 
done < ${FILE}
```